# transform given time into single format 24-hour format

Tags: python, input, time

I got a user input like the example from the photo and made a list with it.

```
n = int(input())

while n != 0:
    row = input()
    a = row.strip().replace(':',' ').split(' ')
    n -= 1
```

How can I get the time given into 24-hour format? I tried using if statement like this

```
if a[2] == "2" and a[4] == "pm":
    a[2]= "14"
```

but when pm is not specified I get stucked. All hours are ordered by time like in the example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAqq3.png)

Comment: Checkout `datetime.strptime`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some weird values, like `14:10 pm`, try this code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def robust_strptime(txt):
    try:
        return dt.strptime(txt, '%H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return dt.strptime(txt, '%I:%M %p')
        except ValueError:
            return dt.strptime(txt, '%H:%M %p')

txt = ['11:58 am', '12:00', '13:32 pm', '13:31', '02:58 PM', '5:48 pm']
for hour in txt:
    time = robust_strptime(hour)
    print('{:10}'.format(hour) + 'was converted to: {}'.format(dt.strftime(time, '%H:%M:%S')))
```

output:

```
11:58 am  was converted to: 11:58:00
12:00     was converted to: 12:00:00
13:32 pm  was converted to: 13:32:00
13:31     was converted to: 13:31:00
02:58 PM  was converted to: 14:58:00
5:48 pm   was converted to: 17:48:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%H - Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23].
```

find below link for more detail,
[enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time)